# Keep a console program running on Amazon EC2 when not RD

Tags: c#, console, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop

I have a console program (C#) that I've built and want to run on Amazon EC2 (Windows). The good part is that the program runs absolutely fine. The problem is that I have to be logged in via Remote Desktop for the console program to continue processing. I have tried leaving the user logged in (just close via the X close) but that was to no avail.

The program is an infinite loop that should just keep processing forever. How can I get the program to run even while not RD'ed in?

Little extra info: I've installed the program in the default (one-click install) way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler to run a console program when you are not logged in.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler

Note that Windows Task Scheduler would have to initiate the program.  That does not allow you to interactively start a console program as an interactive user (i.e. from your RDP session) and then keep it running.

Alternatively, it is fairly straightforward to transform a console program into a windows service.

Comment: Decided to re-create the program as a Windows service, fairly trivial change. Thanks for the input!